# How to reach information already saved in other related models... MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm really new at this and I want to practice queries and tried to make a very different exercise but it didn't went as I expected.

I got three models:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
 info1: String,
 info2: String,
},


 const serviceSchema = new Schema(
{
 name: String,
 legalOwner: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User',
 },
},


const orderSchema = new Schema(
{
 client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
 service: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service' },
 description: String
},
```

My users can behave like a legal owner or a client. I want to show the info that a user set as a LegalOwner, previously. And that is already saved in Mongo, How can I have access that data, is there a query for that? Do I need to set it in my model Order?

```
 const orderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    service: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service' },
    description: String,
    legalOwner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service' },

  },
```

I tried a lot of things on this query. But nothing works ...

```
 await Order.findById(id).populate('service')
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId are stored as _id within mongoDb as far as I am aware of.

Try this

```
const query = { _id: new ObjectID(id)};

await Order.findOne(query).populate('service')
```

Also import ObjectID from mongodb node_module as

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
```